# Sympy: Equation equals zero => How to remove denominator and get factors?

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers, simplify

After some calculations on the complex number z_re and its conjugate z(bar)_re, I get the following equations:

[image: equations]

I simplify and expand and get the second or third of the three equations from the picture. This looks almost like what I want to achieve.

My goal is an equation of the form: `A*z_re*z(bar)_re + B*z_re + C*z(bar)_re + D = 0`.

How can I get rid of the denominator of the second equation (the equation is equal to zero) and extract the factors A, B, C, and D from the equation?
For the example shown above the result should be: A=3, B=-1, C=-1, and D=0

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of your code relate to the picture and how it all relates to the question

Comment: I removed unnecessary comments and code. Summary: I have this sympy expression shown in the picture above and want to extract the factors A, B, C, and D (as described above).

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that will do what you ask. Basically I just expressed your equation, factored it such that it is in the form `<some_fraction> = 0` and got the numerator of that fraction, which is what you need.

```
from sympy import *
z_re = Symbol('z_re',Complex=True)
z_re_c = conjugate(z_re)

e1 = Mul(z_re,Pow(Add(z_re,Integer(-1)),Integer(-1)))
e2 = Mul(z_re,z_re_c,Pow(Add(z_re,Integer(-1)),Integer(-1)),Pow(Add(z_re_c,Integer(-1)),Integer(-1)))
e3 = Mul(z_re_c,Pow(Add(z_re_c,Integer(-1)),Integer(-1)))
e4 = Add(e1,e2,e3)

e5 =e4.factor()
e6 = fraction(e5)[0] # just the numerator
```